# relationship between image pixel dimension and byte array length

Tags: android, image, bitmap, pixel, blobstore

If I know the pixel height and width of an image, can I calculate the size of the byte array? Or would the information be insufficient?

The reason I need this is to get image from blobstore using servingUrl. Since I know (dynamically) the size of the view expecting the image, I want to use that to tell blobstore how to size the image so to save memory, etc. To the best of my knowledge the blobstore whats size information, not dimension.

Comment: hey, did you managed to solve this ? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can estimate the size of byte array like this:

```
size = width * height * 3.
```

The 3 is the  typical number of bytes used to store one pixels= without alpha channel.

If pixel has alpha channel, it will use additional one byte, that is 4 bytes in total.